# Adding Fields to Sharepoint Organization Browser webpart

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, organizational-chart

There is a webpart available in Sharepoint 2010 that lets you view an org chart of users related by the AD manager field. OOB it displays their names, job titles and the content of the 'about me' field. I have been given the requirement to display further user profile fields, in particular telephone numbers. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible. You can use third party alternatives which can display telephone number. For example [Plumsail Org Chart](http://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/) or [1OrgChart](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/sharepoint-reviews-articles/sharepoint-webparts/799-content-and-code-1orgchart)